# how to enhance the screen of my vm?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualization

How can I enhance the size of my virtual machine ?
I installed ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition (lts) on virtualbox but the screen looks to small. When I do CTRL+C the screen becomes bigger but it does not show more as the original small screen. My problem is displayed in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Installing VirtualBox guest additions usually fixes this problem.

To do so:

With the virtual machine running, press `HOSTKEY + D` By Default your host key is usually the right control key.

After a moment a windows should pop up asking you to run software, click the Run button.

VirtualBox guest additions should install, you will probably need to enter your Ubuntu password somewhere along the automated process.

You may need to restart your Virtual Machine for changes to take effect.

Good luck!